# Hotellings statistic

Tags: r

I expected I could proof, if a sample of p-variate normal random vectors has a theoretical mean value, by the hotellings test. But a crosscheck with ks.test, if the distribution from the HottelingsT2 function matches the distribution of the test statistic which is used by HottelingsT2-Test failed. It means that the simulated experiments has not the mean value 0, but obviously they have. So there should be something wrong in context. Are there some mistakes?

```
require(mvtnorm)
require(ICSNP)
subject<-50
treatment<-4
V<-matrix(c(644.03100226056, 184.319025225855, 572.5312199559, 143.106678641056, 184.319025225855, 73.5310268006399, 230.838267981476, 130.977532385651, 572.5312199559, 230.838267981476, 736.378779002912, 429.445506266528, 143.106678641056, 130.977532385651, 429.445506266528, 435.124191935888),treatment,treatment)

experiment<-list()
R<-3000
seed<-split(1:(R*subject),1:R)
for(i in 1:R){
  e<-c()
  for(j in 1:subject){
    set.seed(seed[[i]][j]) 
    e<-c(e,rmvnorm(mean=rep(0,treatment),sigma=V,n=1,method="chol"))
   }
   experiment<-c(experiment,list(matrix(e,subject,treatment,byrow=T)))
 }

 p.values<-c()
 for(e in experiment){
   fit<-lm(e~1)
   p.values<-c(p.values,HotellingsT2(e, mu=rep(0,treatment))[["p.value"]])
 }

 ks.test(p.values, punif,alternative = "two.sided")
```

Comment: Belongs on cross-validated instead of SO. http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thx for the link, I cant find a related post to my question. Do you see some mistakes in the simulation?

Comment: In a other point of view, I only compare if the ecdf of the test statistic with the theoretical F-distribution giving by the ANOVA-Framework. I cant see the mistake in this simple montecarlo studie.

Comment: This belongs here IMO. The question is not about the statistical/theoretical properties of a test, but whether there is a mistake in the code. Now if someone were to point out that the OP's assumptions about statistical properties were wrong, then it might belong on CrossValidated.

Comment: I agree, IMO the tag usage-statistics I use in point of view if there is no mistake in the programming code.

Comment: I am interested in this question from both a statistical and a programming point of view but am having a little bit of trouble following your procedure and also your question. Can you please restate your question a little more succinctly?

Comment: Also, where did the values in V come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked the code, but I wouldn't be surprised if this was the same problem as described in Klaus' other post: [Using Kolmogorov Smirnov Test in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381214/using-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-in-r). Basically, don't put `set.seed` in the middle of the loop: set it once, at the top of the code, and leave it alone afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

Hong Ooi is correct about this being a problem with `set.seed`. I ran your code as it was posted and got the following results:

```
> ks.test(p.values, punif,alternative = "two.sided")

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  p.values
D = 0.0615, p-value = 2.729e-10
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

But if you change your code such that:

```
... everything the same before here ...
experiment <- list()
R <- 3000 # experiment
set.seed(42) # set new seed
for (i in 1:R) { # for each of 3000 experiments
  e <- c() # empty vector
  for (j in 1:subject){ # for each of 50 subjects
    e <- c(e,rmvnorm(mean=rep(0,treatment),sigma=V,n=1,method="chol"))
  }
  experiment <- c(experiment,list(matrix(e,subject,treatment,byrow=T)))
}
... everything the same after here ...
```

Then you get the following:

```
> ks.test(p.values, punif,alternative = "two.sided")

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  p.values
D = 0.0122, p-value = 0.7613
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Essentially by continuing to set random seeds anew at every iteration, even though you are careful to choose a different value, you are still removing the independence of the successive draws.