# Using Kolmogorov Smirnov Test in R

Tags: r, anova

I designed 3000 experiments, so that in one experiment there are 4 groups (treatment), in each group there are 50 individuals (subjects). For each experiment I do a standard one way ANOVA and proof if their p.values has a uni probability function under the null-hypothesis, but ks.test rejects this assumption and I cant see why?

```
subject<-50
treatment<-4
experiment<-list()
R<-3000
seed<-split(1:(R*subject),1:R)
for(i in 1:R){
  e<-c()
  for(j in 1:subject){
    set.seed(seed[[i]][j]) 
    e<-c(e,rmvnorm(mean=rep(0,treatment),sigma=diag(3,4),n=1,method="chol"))
   }
  experiment<-c(experiment,list(matrix(e,subject,treatment,byrow=T)))
 }

 p.values<-c()
for(e in experiment){
  d<-data.frame(response=c(e),treatment=factor(rep(1:treatment,each=subject)))
  p.values<-c(p.values,anova(lm(response~treatment,d))[1,"Pr(>F)"])
 }

 ks.test(p.values, punif,alternative = "two.sided")
```

Comment: Does the phrase "correction for multiple comparisons" mean anything to you?

Comment: No not realy, I read it out on wikipedia and cant see the relevance for my simulation. I designed independent experiment and test each experiment for only one hypothesis, not more.

Comment: @Zack It's a simulation study. OP is calculating a single P-value per experiment, but repeating the procedure multiple times to examine the properties of the P-value statistic.

Comment: You shouldn't be resetting the random seed in the middle of the simulation. If you're after reproducibility, set it once, at the top of your code, and leave it alone afterwards.

Comment: I do not understand, the seeds are declared in the top and they are different for all experiments. If you use `e<-c(e,rnorm(treatment,0,3))` instad of `rmvnorm(mean=rep(0,treatment),sigma=diag(3,4),n=1,method="chol")` I get better results. Is there a explanation for that behavior?.

Comment: You seem to have a solution, but allow me to elaborate on the multiple comparisons thing: You're doing 3000 comparisons.  With the usual 5% confidence level, that means you will have on the order of 150 false positives.  That you only do one comparison *per experiment* does not save you from needing to correct for having done 3000 comparisons *overall*.

Comment: (That said, I don't properly understand what you're trying to accomplish here - you're doing a meta-test of the hypothesis that the P-values of 3000 F-tests will be uniformly distributed?  I don't see why that would be a useful thing to do.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I commented out the lines in your code that change the random seed, and got a P-value of .34. That was with an unknown seed, so for reproducibility, I did `set.seed(1)` and ran it again. This time, I got a P-value of 0.98.

As to why this makes a difference, I'm not an expert in PRNGs, but any decent generator will ensure successive draws are statistically independent for all practical purposes. The best ones will ensure the same for greater lags, eg the Mersenne Twister which is R's default PRNG guarantees it for lags up to 623 (IIRC). In fact, meddling with the seed is likely to impair the statistical properties of the draws.

Your code is also doing things in a really inefficient way. You're creating a list for the experiments, and adding one item for each experiment. *Within* each experiment, you also create a matrix, and add a row for each observation. Then you do something very similar for the P-values. I'll see if I can fix that up.

This is how I'd replace your code. Strictly speaking I could make it even tighter, by avoiding formulas, creating the bare model matrix, and calling `lm.fit` directly. But that would mean having to manually code up the ANOVA test rather than simply calling `anova`, which is more trouble than it's worth.

```
set.seed(1) # or any other number you like

x <- factor(rep(seq_len(treatment), each=subject))
p.values <- sapply(seq_len(R), function(r) {
    y <- rnorm(subject * treatment, s=3)
    anova(lm(y ~ x))[1,"Pr(>F)"]
})
ks.test(p.values, punif,alternative = "two.sided")


        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  p.values
D = 0.0121, p-value = 0.772
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Comment: If you only use set.seed(1) for every r.n. generation, that change the design of the experiments. Regarding your comment about the efficent of the code, I know the code is not efficient in this case but I use this skeleton for mor complex things and tried by copy paste the specific design above. My question refers only on the r.n. generation.

Comment: I'm not using `set.seed(1)` inside your loops. I set the seed ONCE, at the start, and then I run your code (after commenting out the lines that reset the seed).

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood the meaning of set.seed. I thought I have to set it before every call of a r.n. generating function to get repeatable data. The second thing is that I got "good values" if I use rnorm also in my virtuos way for setting the seeds but not if I use rmvnorm. So I think to set a seed once will solve the problem.

Comment: No problem. See if this also fixes the issues in your other post re: Hotelling's T.